# How to iterate only a specific value position in a ruby hash?

Tags: ruby, hashmap

I know the first value of all `@@logHash` keys contains IP addresses. I want to iterate just that position to create keys for a new hash if its not a duplicate key.

Here is what I have but I know it can't be right...

```
def ipaddresses(@@logHash)
    @@ipHash = Hash.new
    @@logHash[1].each_value do | value |
       if @@ipHash.has_key?(value)
          @@ipHash[value] += "#"
       else
          @@ipHash[value] = "#"
       end
       puts ""
       @@ipHash.sort.each { |key,value| puts "The frequency of #{key} is |#{value}"}
    end
end
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Lisa

Answer (score 0):

Here's a reworked version that might be closer to what you want:

```
def ipaddresses(logHash)
  ipHash = Hash.new(0)

  logHash[1].each_value do | value |
    ipHash[value] += 1
    puts ""
  end

  ipHash.sort.each { |key,value| puts "The frequency of #{key} is |#{value}"}
end
```

It's not clear why you're using `@@` class variables in a method like this. They're very unusual to be using in any context. For temporary variables or method arguments, no prefix is required.

Here `Hash.new(0)` creates a new hash with a default value of `0`. This avoids having to pre-initialize the keys before using them as in Ruby adding anything to `nil` is considered invalid.

Comment: I'm verry very new to ruby but this is a method among multiple methods in a class and I want those hashes to be used in multiple methods so that's why they are class variables. Is this not correct?

Comment: So this "logHash[1].each_value do | value |" does indeed work to iterate just the first value of all the keys in logHash? That was my main concern.

Comment: You should be using `@`-type instance variables to share them among a singular instance of a class, not `@@` which are shared amongst *all* instances of a class. If you make the mistake of using `@@` variables, you will see data bleed from one instance to another. In either case, arguments to methods do not have an `@` prefix of any sort.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a class variable (or anything other than a local variable) as an argument. It does not make sense to do that. Arguments are something that are passed together with a method call. If you want to refer to a class variable within the method definition, you can just refer to that directly. Having it passed via argument is redundant, and is hence made impossible by design.